# Twitter reverse auth returning 401 (using MonoTouch TweetStation code)

Tags: xamarin.ios, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm following [Twitter's instructions](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth) on how to perform reverse auth within iOS to get an access token, but I'm stuck on step 1. I am using [TweetStation's OAuth code](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation/blob/master/TweetStation/Utilities/OAuthAuthorizer.cs) as a template.

The current [AcquireRequestToken()](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TweetStation/blob/master/TweetStation/Utilities/OAuthAuthorizer.cs#L143) method works fine- so I know it's not an error with creating the signature, etc. However, when I add the reverse_auth header like so:

```
var headers = new Dictionary<string,string> () {
    { "oauth_callback", OAuth.PercentEncode (config.Callback) },
    { "oauth_consumer_key", config.ConsumerKey },
    { "oauth_nonce", MakeNonce () },
    { "oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1" },
    { "oauth_timestamp", MakeTimestamp () },
    { "oauth_version", "1.0" },
    { "x_auth_mode", "reverse_auth" }};
```

I get a 401 response. Am I mis-reading Twitter's instructions? Is there something else I should be doing to adjust this initial request? Grateful for any input on this, as I'm totally stumped.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer- the headers dictionary itself is never actually sent, so the x_auth_mode value isn't either. The solution was to add it to the POST body:

```
var res = wc.UploadString (config.RequestTokenUrl,"POST", "x_auth_mode=reverse_auth");
```

Now it works great.